# How to set up login page in Spring Boot 2 with WebFlux?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, thymeleaf, spring-webflux, spring-cloud-gateway

I have created Spring Boot 2 WebFlux application (based on Spring Cloud Gateway project) and now try to configure custom login page instead of standard:

```
@Bean
SecurityWebFilterChain springWebFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
    return http.httpBasic().and()
            .authorizeExchange()
            .anyExchange().authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin().loginPage("/login")
            .and()
            .csrf().disable()
            .build();
}
```

I tried to use Thymeleaf to render this page by means of login html page creation and controller setup:

```
@Controller
public class LoginController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/login")
    public Mono<String> getLoginPage() {
        return Mono.just("/templates/login.html");
    }
}
```

But it don't working. Can anybody explain how to do this and should I using Thymeleaf at all? Maybe this have already implemented and is on GitHub?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
@Controller
public class LoginController {

    @GetMapping("/login")
    public String getLoginPage() {
        // assuming that Thymeleaf is present
        // and a valid src/main/resources/templates/login.html template 
        return "login";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for response. That helped for problem solving. But now I don't understand why view not resolved. Application context by some reason doesn't contains Thymeleaf view resolver.

Comment: More precisely Thymeleaf beans contained in application context, but by some reason view not resolved.